# Adding totals at bottom of report

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

Totaly new to reports and also having difficulties with terminology so googling returns a lot of irrelevant info. In need to add up my columns in the table built in a .rdlc file dynamically with values fed from a stored proc.

So basically, imagine a Excel document with six columns and a variable number of rows. At the bottom, I need to total up each column individually, similar to `=SUM(A1:D1)` as you would in a spreadsheet.

Presetnly I have two rows in the .rdlc designer, the column headers and data row. I've added a third row for totals but that added the totals row under each data row, which is not what I need. I want the total to show up only once at the bottom.

How would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I've figured it out intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

Expression `Sum(fields!Columnname1.Value)` sum up the values of column.
i.e. If you have column Amount in your dataset, you should put expression Sum(fields!Amount.Value)